# Access and Render variable value of one component into another component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 components in my reactjs application i.e. VideoStream.js, Location.js CamSelect.js , In CamSelect components i have created a dropdown using select materialUI. When my page load, by default it should set the option as **cam1** and selected value as **cam1's url** .Now when i select any option from the dropdown then i am storing the value of selected option in the **selected** state variable just like shown in the code below:

CamSelect.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Select, MenuItem, FormControl, InputLabel } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./CamSelect.css"

export default class CamSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentCity: localStorage.getItem("city"),
        data: [
            {
                location: "abc",
                link: [
                    {name: "cam1", url: "https://...."},
                    {name: "cam2", url: "https://...."}

                ]
                
            },
            {
                location: "xyz",
                link: [
                  {name: "cam1", url: "https://...."},
                ]
                
            },
        ],
        selected: '',
      
    };

  }

// set default dropdown option "cam1" and it value on page load
  componentDidMount ()  {
    this.state.data.map(ur => {
      if(this.state.currentCity == ur.location){
        this.setState({selected: ur.link[0].url})
        localStorage.setItem("url", this.state.selected)
      }
    })
    
  }
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ selected: event.target.value, name: event.target.name });
    
  };
  
  renderOptions() {
    return this.state.data.map((dt, i) => {
      
      if(this.state.currentCity == dt.location){
       
        return dt.link.map((lnk, index) => {
          
        return (
            <MenuItem
                label="Select a camera"
                value={lnk.url}
                key={index}
                name={lnk.name}
            >
                {lnk.name}
            </MenuItem>
             )
            })
           
            }
            
          }
    )
        };

  render() {
    return (
      <FormControl className="camera-select" style={{ minWidth: "100px"}}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label" style={{color:"white"}}>Camera</InputLabel>
        <Select
        // defaultValue="cam1"
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          className="camera-text-color"
          value={this.state.selected}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          {this.renderOptions()}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}
```

In the **VideoStream.js** component i want to use **selected** variable and render it in the player inside the videostream component. Video will play based on the value i selected in the  CamSelect.js component and also **video should switch depending on the value select in the dropdown**

**When i try to use localStorage then it's not working and showing as  in the console.**

Here is a code for VideoStream.js:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import { 
    Card, 
    CardContent, 
    CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import "./VideoStream.css"

const VideoStream = () => {
   let currentUrl = localStorage.getItem("url")
 
       return (
         <Card className="video-player">
          <label className="video-label">Live Feed </label>
             <CardContent className="video-cardContent">
               <ReactPlayer
                  url= {currentUrl}
                  width="100%"
                  height="250px"
                  playing={true}
                  muted={true}
                  controls
                  className="hls-player"
               /> 
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
       );
     };
export default VideoStream;
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Hi @ChrisG, Thanks for the response, i tried lifting state concept and it's worked for me. I have one more question i.e. in CamSelect.js i have <menuitem> tag and inside that i have "value" & "name" attributes so, whenever i make any selection from the dropdown then only "value" atrributes's value i am getting and for "name" attributes it's showing undefined. How can i resolve this?

Comment: At least with standard HTML, <option> elements don't have a `name`, the <select> has. The options have a *value* and optionally text content that shows a nicely formatted representation of the value. When the form is sent, the <select> has a `name` (its own) and a `value` (that of the selected option). If you want to read additional info besides the URL, use the array index of `.link` as value for the dropdown and read both name and url from the array.

Comment: Hi @ChrisG, Thanks for the suggestions, can u pls explain with a small example like how i can pass the array index and get both name and url from value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Ok, let me make it clear, In the camselect.js i have an object array `Data` and inside it, it has `Link` array. So whenever user will select any option from the dropdown then i want to get both `url` and `name` fields 's value of selected option. 
Here i am only getting `url` value when `handleChange` event is happening but i also wanted `name` field value based on selection. 
Here is the output of `handleChange` event.target where name field is showing as `undefined`:

**event {value: 'https: //...', name: undefined}**